# Image and text alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I took a solution from here earlier to solve some div alignment problems, just when I thought all was sorted - adding an image into any of my containers causes text to be misaligned elsewhere, see image and code below.

The image in the code is just a blue rectangle, any image will do.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

[image]

```
<style>
    .row {
            display: table;
            width: 98%;
            min-width: 440px;
            border: solid 5px black; 
            border-top: none;
            margin-top: -4px; 
        }

        .left {
            width: 150px; 
            border-right: solid 5px black;
            display:table-cell;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .middle {
            width:auto;
            display:table-cell;
            font-size: 9.5pt;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .right {
            width: 150px; 
            border-left: solid 5px black;
            display:table-cell;
            background-color: black;
            padding-left: 5px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
</style>

<div class="row">
        <div class="left">
            <img alt="" src="/Images/Blue.png" border="0"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="middle"> 
            Text which should be at the top
        </div>
        <div class="right">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try adding `vertical-align: top;` to .middle

Comment: I've spent half an hour messing about with all the display options, absolute position etc and its that simple... Need to up my CSS game... That works perfectly, thanks very much for the help.

Comment: when there's an inline level element (plain text is an inline element) you just think about the vertical alignement as long as there's height for the element to move